# Is there a way to find the application in which i have dropped an image from my browser to a native application in my OS?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, drag-and-drop

I am building a chrome extension, where i want to drop data based on application i am dropping my image so that i can set the data based on the application i am dropping to. For example, if i am dropping image to a word file, it would be a text which says TEXT_WORD, if i am dropping to an ms-excel, it would be a text which says TEXT_EXCEL.

So, is it possible to know to which application have we dropped to by any method.

Currently what i know is i have control to set data in the dragstart eventlistener

```
canvas.addEventListener("dragstart", (e) => {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", "TEXT_WORD");
});
```

But i want to do this while i am dropping based on the application(MS Word/MS Excel/Notepad) i am dropping to, so that i can change the data based on the application.

Comment: I doubt you can get the application, but you might be able to get the MIME type.

Comment: mime type of the application i am dropping to?

Comment: No, of the file. The application info is not exposed.